# Gnome3 .desktop app-launcher directory hierachy Explaination

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, .desktop, 18.10

I'd like to rename the gnome shell program name/identifier of an installed program, but I couldn't find the location of it's .desktop file, which contains the specifications of these shortcuts/symbols. Can anyone explain the hierarchy of these .desktop files to me?

I already know, that `~/.local/share/applications/` can be used for user defined gnome shell app-launchers. Also found the directory for the apt installed applications, it is `/usr/share/applications/`. But since I installed this app using `snap` and others using `apt`/`aptitude`, they're not in these directories.

What's the hierarchy of these directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. You should find the `.desktop` launchers for snap applications.